# API name for Converted Amounts

Tags: rest-api, api, soap-api, soap, opportunity-lineitem

Within the Opp object there is a Revenue Field. You can choose the base currency but also opt to show next to it what the converted currency is if you are U.S. based for instance. I'm looking for ALL the converted amounts in base USD but can only pull via the api amounts as entered. Basically, I can't find the API name for what's in the parenthesis.

EXAMPLE: GBP 76,800 (USD 116,346)

I only get the GBP but also want to pull in the USD.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`convertCurrency`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_currency_fields.htm) function to get the converted amount. This topic also describes how to find values that are above a certain value in a certain currency, allowing for conversion.

Examples:

```
SELECT Id, convertCurrency(AnnualRevenue)
FROM Account

SELECT Id, Name
FROM Opportunity
WHERE Amount > USD5000
```